# mongoDB - update document using $set and a object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an object which contains multiple values from input fields. Now I want to update a specific collection. I did it like this:

```
var info = {age: t.find('input[name=age]').value, organization: t.find('input[name=organization]').value};
Users.update({_id: userId}, {$set: {profile: info}});
```

Now, the problem is that this removes `profile` values which exist before the update operation.
Is it possible to keep values in the document, which are not part of the `info` object?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot notation in the `$set` keys to update individual fields in embedded objects:

```
var set = {
    'profile.info.age': t.find('input[name=age]').value,
    'profile.info.organization': t.find('input[name=organization]').value
};
Users.update({_id: userId}, {$set: set});
```